How to understand DeepSeek's offline token usage estimator?
DeepSeek has a simple python code to calculate token usage offline but I don't really understand what it is showing.
For example:
result = tokenizer.encode("This is a test")
print(result)

> Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.
[100000, 1567, 317, 245, 1727]

What is the result printed to screen? Is it the input converted to input tokens? So I should care mostly about the number of tokens generated, as that is how they charge you?


What is the result printed to screen?

A list of token IDs.
100000, 1567, 317, 245, 1727 = [special token], This, is, a, test

I should care mostly about the number of tokens generated, as that is how they charge you?

Given a model, the price solely depends on the number of tokens generated (aka output tokens) and the number of tokens in the prompt (aka input tokens).
FYI, OpenAI calculator:  https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer


Demo showing IDs and tokens: https://observablehq.com/@simonw/gpt-tokenizer

